# How to make FirewallD and hybrid-sleep work together?

Tags: 16.04, suspend, hibernate, firewalld

I have firewalld working following the answer [Firewalld does not start at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913943/firewalld-does-not-start-at-boot).

I have hybrid-sleep working following [How do I use pm-suspend-hybrid by default instead of pm-suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145443/how-do-i-use-pm-suspend-hybrid-by-default-instead-of-pm-suspend/781957?s=1|0.4681#781957)

However, if firewalld is active and I close the lid to initiate hybrid-sleep, then the system freezes with black screen. If I initiate normal sleep via **power cog menu > Suspend** then the computer suspends fine. I can also get the computer to hybrid-sleep if I stop the firewalld service before putting the computer to hybrid-sleep.

My computer is running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTE with HWE.

My question is how do I prevent the conflict between firewallD and hybrid-sleep?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update April 23, 2018: Fixing the root cause solves this problem

**Root Cause**

The service file - `/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service` says firewalld conflict with `ebtables.service` which is enabled by default in Ubuntu 16.04.

**Solution**

Disable and mask `ebtables.service` with the following two commands:

```
sudo systemctl disable ebtables
sudo systemctl mask ebtables
```

**This resolves the issue with FirewallD and hybrid-sleep**  and the associated problem of [Firewalld does not start at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913943/firewalld-does-not-start-at-boot)

Thanks to [alfred's answer to the above question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913943/firewalld-does-not-start-at-boot/1027467#1027467)

## Original answer:

**Stop `firewalld` before hybrid-sleep and start it at resume**

**Background**

Put a bash script file in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`. Immediately before entering system suspend, hibernate, or hybrid-sleep the `systemd-suspend.service` (and the respective equivalents) will run the bash script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` and pass two arguments to them. The first argument will be **pre**, the second either **suspend**, **hibernate**, or **hybrid-sleep** depending on the chosen action.

Immediately after leaving system suspend, hibernate or hybrid-sleep the same bash script is run, but the first argument is now **post**.

Source: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-suspend.service.html

**How to do it:**

Create a text file: `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/firewalld-sleep.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1/$2 in
    pre/*)
    # Disable firewalld before hybrid-sleep
    systemctl stop firewalld.service    
    ;;
    post/*)
    # Enable firewalld after hybrid-sleep
    systemctl start firewalld.service
    ;;
esac
```

Make the file executable. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/484718/how-to-make-a-file-executable for details.

Note, the script stops the `firewalld` before any of the three types of sleep/hybernate/hybrid-sleep and starts it again at resume.

Now `firewalld` and `hybrid-sleep` will coexist and system will not freeze if you close the lid while `firewalld` is running.

Hope this helps